# WebAPI 2 Custom Model Binder is never Invoked

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am using latest bit of WebAPI 2. I am running into problem where default ModelBinder is not surfacing the posted value properly. I did verify that value is correctly posted back to the Server, i am able to retrieve that using Request Object. So decided to implement my own custom Model Binder. Now i am running into problem where this Custom Binder is never Invoked, only the Default Binder is invoked. what i am i missing ?

WebAPI Method

```
  public IHttpActionResult PutOrg([ModelBinder(typeof(MyOrgModelBinder))] Org org)
{

}
```

Custom ModelBinder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
using System.Web.Http.ValueProviders;

namespace SM4.Models
{

    public class MyOrgModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext controllerContext,
                                ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {

            var org = new Org
             {
                 OrgCode_PK = request.Form.Get("OrgCode_PK"),
                 OrgHeadCode_FK = request.Form.Get("OrgHeadCode_FK"),
                 Code = request.Form.Get("Code"),
                 Name = "THIS is FROM BINDER",
                 Description = request.Form.Get("Description"),
                 Address1 = request.Form.Get("Address1"),
                 Address2 = request.Form.Get("Address2"),
                 CountryCode_FK = request.Form.Get("CountryCode_FK"),
                 StateCode_FK = request.Form.Get("StateCode_FK"),
                 CityCode_FK = request.Form.Get("CityCode_FK"),
                 ZIP = request.Form.Get("ZIP"),
                 RowStatusCode_FK = request.Form.Get("RowStatusCode_FK"),
                 EffectiveDate = DateTime.ParseExact(request.Form.Get("EffectiveDate"), "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                 TerminationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(request.Form.Get("TerminationDate"), "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
             };

            bindingContext.Model = org;
            return true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: public IHttpActionResult PutOrg([FromBody]